# Expectation Propagation - Computing mean and variance of error function

Tags: optimization, moments, kullback-leibler, approximate-inference

I'm still trying to wrap my head around computing the moments for the expectation propagation algorithm and whether I can use it for the following example:

say i have a product of distributions which i want to use EP to estimate the posterior for using some multidimensional data set $x,y$: 
$p(y | \mu , \sigma , \beta , w, x) = e^{-\beta E_D}$ 

where $E_D =( \sum we^{\frac{-||x-\mu||^2}{\sigma^2}}) - y$

and $\mu , \sigma , \beta , w$ are of some known dimension

How do I go about computing the moments? for each distribution do i assume that the distribution is separable? i.e. $q(\mu)q(\sigma)q(\beta)q(w) \approx p$, where q is some normal distribution ? 
If so, is the correct method to determine the optimal moments for each parameter to minimize the KL divergence, $KL(P_i\prod Q' || Q_i\prod Q')$?

Sorry if I am completely on the wrong track, I'm entirely new to this field of inference and lack any sort of intuition.